# found breakpoints not sure which media queries to use

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have went through and found all of the em and px breakpoints in my website but I am not sure which of the following media queries to use:

- Max-Device-Width
- Min-Device-Width
- Max-Width
- Min-Width

For example: On my website my navigation breaks anywhere below 43.75em. What would be the proper or best used media query for my site. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. I have self taught myself HTML5 & CSS3 just can't seem to grasp Media Queries.

I am currently using max-width but the media query doesn't seem to be functioning when the browser is resized smaller than 43.75em.

-Luke

Comment: max-width would be suitable, You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for better understanding

Comment: This link still doesn't say exactly which Media Query that would be best to use.

Comment: I currently do use max-width but this does not make the media query do anything when the browser is small than 43.75em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your media query is not dependent on any device, its only dependent on width (43.75em), you can do

```
@media (max-width: 43.75em) { ... }
```

But specifying width in em will make it dependent on browser size dependent set by user. So if you are setting your base size it will be perfectly fine (genrally people keep 1em = 16px) You can also set screen media query, screen works for desktop and mobile both

```
@media screen and (max-width: 43.75em) { ... }
```

Comment: This isn't a valid answer because I am trying to avoid Pixels.

Comment: Have updated the answer to remove the pixel thing but present the same point

Comment: How do I go about setting my base size? I understood that the base size is already set to 1em = ~16px

Comment: do html, body { font-size: 16px; } or you can use meyer reset css or http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to start from basic uniform layout

Comment: After doing this my site still doesn't respond to my media queries when I resize my browser.

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle or working sample?

Comment: I went to jsfiddle and for some reason it works there? But not on my website. Any reasons why this would be?

Comment: Please check your website's email.

Comment: Replied on your mail, adding it here. 
In body background you are setting background-image but on media-query you are setting background-color so image is getting preferences over color.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Max-Width, this is because you are trying to be responsive to the viewable area, meaning the browser viewport, using Max-Device-Width will make it be the entire device, which might be very different depending on what browser they are using and the UI used by the browser. I like using Max over Min just because it's easier to digest when trying to understand when looking at how my rules will react as the browser increases in width.

Comment: I am using max-width but when I resize my browser the media query takes no effect.